# Delphi XE: how to disable declaration wrapping?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I haven't been using Delphi these last few years (last version I worked with was D2005) and I need to do some work in DelphiXE now. My question is, how do I disable declaration wrapping in the Delphi IDE? currently I use modelmaker's code explorer to unwrap them, but I cannot imagine that this can't be disabled! I've tried editing the right margins in the editor options, but that doesn't seem to help anything.

Below is an example of what I get when I add an event procedure via the object inspector of my treeview control:

```
procedure
    TfrmSomeLongInheritedEditFormName.vstStringTreeviewComponentAdvancedHeaderDraw(
    Sender: TVTHeader; var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo; const Elements:
    THeaderPaintElements);
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

But i want it like this:

```
procedure TfrmSomeLongInheritedEditFormName.vstStringTreeviewComponentAdvancedHeaderDraw(Sender: TVTHeader; var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo; const Elements: THeaderPaintElements);
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

Is it possible or do I need to keep editing the code by hand (or by using code explorer)?

Comment: I think you are in for some disappointment

Comment: what is this sorcery? :)

Comment: If you post code to StackOverflow or other sites, you probably want 'wrapping'. In your post above, I can see (essentially) all of the code in the first snippet without doing any scrolling, but I can not see a single argument in the second snippet without doing a lot of horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I found it in the modelmaker tools! will post as answer, since the IDE itself does not seem to have this functionality.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: if I am posting some code to demonstrate code I want NOT to be wrapped, it's probably not very wise to wrap my example text, now is it? :P thus you NEED to scroll here..

Comment: there are two places to change, don't know if its translated correct Formating/Delphi/WordWrap/right margins and 
Editor-Options/right margins

Comment: @Bummi Neither of those seem to influence this behaviour at least when I tried

Comment: @bummi I can confirm what David Heffernan says. I've tried as well, doesn't work.

Comment: @TedOnTheNet: My point was simply that it is strange not to want the wrapping, because you might want to post your code at SO (or at other sites) in the future. Also, even if you only read the code in the Delphi IDE, IMHO it is simpler if you don't need to scroll. (If you have a large, wide, screen, you still need to move your eyes a lot if you have long lines.)

Comment: makes me wonder using XE I did set both places to 300 and no wrap does happen even CTRL+D won't add wrapping

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand i use a lot of stringtreeviews which have long declarations. I like them on one line because I know which params they have, I have wide monitors IF i need to read them nontheless and I think multiline declarations are messy. I am a clean guy :P

Comment: @bummi I did that on XE3 mind you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan did not mind, but with even XE3 and the mentioned settings I won't get wrapping, even 250 characters of declaration are not wrapped.

Comment: I don't know what kind of zombie IDE you guys are running but just like bummi I can remove this wrapping by assigning a higher value to the Right margin option in : Editor Options > Display > Right Margin.

Comment: @bummi OK, me too now. I had the right margin not visible. When you make it visible, I see the same behaviour as you. Please do add an answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan could you have a look to my answer since I am not in possession of a english version?

Comment: @bummi Done. I'm on XE3 so hopefully the layout is close enough in XE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two places to change the settings for the right margin:

- Formatter | Delphi | Line breaks | Right margin
- Editor Options | Display | Right Margin

Setting the former to a large value is enough to ensure that IDE generated methods do not wrap. Set the latter to a large value to ensure that the code formatter does not wrap long lines.

Answer (score 1):

In Modelmaker's MMX tools there is a way. Go to the Modelmaker code explorer options > Pascal > editing. In the group "Code lay out" there is a "wrap margin". I've increased the value from 80 to 400. works fine now!

As far as I know, there's no way to do it in the IDE.

Comment: External tools are indeed the way to do this: Delphi does not have a built-in setting for it. You can use the GExperts or might be able to use (forgot from which Delphi version it is included) the built-in Delphi code formatter.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers bummi and Peter have shown a way to do this using the plain vanilla IDE

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. Somehow I missed the `right margin` option in the big set of code formatter options.